# furry output from xpdf in full-screen mode

Tags: latex

I'm running `fvwm` as a desktop manager, and have multiple pages open.
When using `xpdf` in full screen mode, and switching from one page, where I'm running latex, to another, where I have `xpdf` open in full-screen mode, I get furry output, as this screenshot shows.     The problem doesn't arise if I run `xpdf` with the default geometry.

[image]

It's easy enough to redraw the screen and get crisp output, but it would be nice not to always have to do this.     Is there some way to avoid it?